# Custom setting field value not working inside add_action init hook

Tags: settings-api, options, init

I have added custom setting options page under WordPress settings and those are working perfectly. I have tested their values also. But when I am using those values inside function file within add_action init hook to perform something on form submission, those values are returning as null. Everything is working except those values return as null. A few examples will really help me! Thanks in advance :)

```
    add_action('init', 'myFunc');
    function myFunc(){
        $myoptions   = get_option( 'custom_option' );
        $trueorfalse = $myoptions['my_swicth'];
        $alertemail  = $myoptions['alert_email']; // both working outside
        if( 1 == $trueorfalse && 'test@example.com' == $alertemail ){
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please let me know if my question is not valid! or anyone need more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Problem was I was retrieving those setting option values outside the if statement `if(isset($_POST['formvalue'])){  }` and using them inside it. For that reason values were actually not pulled from database.